# How to get a list from a queryset in Django

Tags: django

Consider the following django code

```
phonenumbers = othermodel.objects.filter( company=mymodel.company,
                                         date_overwritten__isnull=True
                                       ).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

This is returning another QuerySet object instead of a python list, the first object in the queryset returned is a {valuesListQuerySet} which is an empty list and this is correct because my whole model/table othermodel is currently empty

What am i missing? and how do i get just the {valuesListQuerySet} as a normal python list even if its empty

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

Comment: Why do you need it as a list, specifically? Part of how to write idiomatic Python is to rely on duck-typing; a queryset supports almost all of the functionality of a list. There are occasions when you need to explicitly convert, but it's certainly not a matter of course.

Comment: i am using the result in another query, newquery.message_set.exclude(originator=phonenumbers) what then happens is the newquery inherits and appends the phonenumbers query, but when i look at the concatenation it has a SELECT U0."originator"  now U0 seems to be system generated and it messes the whole thing up

Comment: You need to be more explicit about how it 'messes things up'. It makes it a sub-query, which is usually more efficient than doing two separate queries. And your deleted comment to rob's deleted answer is simply wrong: values_list returns a ValuesListQuerySet, not a list, but if you really do need a list you just pass it to `list()`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman This is not working on Django 3.0 & Python 3.7. On Django 3.0 it is returning the QuerySet class instead of ValuesListQuerySet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [django doc says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

> If you don’t pass any values to values_list(), it will return all the
>   fields in the model, in the order they were declared.
>
> Note that this method returns a ValuesListQuerySet. This class behaves
>   like a list. Most of the time this is enough, but if you require an
>   actual Python list object, you can simply call list() on it, which
>   will evaluate the queryset.

So you could call:

```
list(phonenumbers)
```

Comment: This is not working on Django 3.0+ & Python 3. 

*** Error in argument: '(phonenumbers)'